# Javascript will not load for anonymous users

Tags: 8, users, javascript

I have a controller with a route that has some javascript attached to it as a library.  When logged in as any user (admin or standard) the JS loads just fine.  When anonymous, the library file is loaded, but Drupal JS is not.

How the library is defined:

```
my_javascript:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_javascript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

In the console the error says:

> ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined
>
> < anonymous >                      http://example.com/themes/custom/my_theme/js/my_javascript.js:7:3
>
> < anonymous >                      http://example.com/themes/custom/my_theme/js/my_javascript.js:6:2

The lines in the JS the error is referring to are:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myScripts = {
```

This is the case for all browsers.  JS works fine when logged in as any user, but when anonymous, Drupal's JS does not load.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code in the question appears to be similar to what was done in Drupal 7. In Drupal 8, the dependencies for your javascript need to be explicitly defined and it is a good idea to pass them through the closure as well. You can read more about the [Javascript API in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) on the new documentation pages.

```
my_javascript:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_javascript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal



(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myScripts = {};
)(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding more dependencies to the library definition and adding a hook to add the JS again, and render libraries.

New library definition:

```
my_javascript:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_javascript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

Hook to render libraries:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_theme/my_javascript';
  \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($libraries);
}
```

Update: The hook was not needed, but adding the Drupal object in behaviors correctly for D8 was.  Accepted another answer instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are calling `drupal_render` in your preprocess. You should not need to do any of that to add JavaScript code in your theme. You only need to add libraries.yml definition.

Comment: The is a hook specific for adding attachments. You should use it instead of hook_preprocess_page

Comment: @mradcliffe you're right